# What does "GHTJK" stand for in this part of a Wiktionary: entry: "...composition ⿸丆卜(GHTJK) or ⿻丆"

Tags: character-components

I generally understand the Ideographic Description Characters (IDSes) and the Ideographic Description Sequences,for CJK strokes and components but the abbreviation  GHTJK in this entry and GHTK in others has me baffled: 
"Han character
不 (radical 1, 一+3, 4 strokes, cangjie input 一火 (MF), four-corner 10900, composition ⿸丆卜(GHTJK) or ⿻丆..."
[Source](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D)

Comment: Can you provide the link to the wikitionary entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're one-letter abbreviations for different standards, because some characters appear differently in different standards. From https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:Han_char#Notes:

- G = the PRC and Singapore standard (referring to [Table of General Standard Chinese Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_General_Standard_Chinese_Characters) 通用規範漢字表);
- H = Hong Kong, referring to [List of Graphemes of Commonly-Used Chinese Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Graphemes_of_Commonly-Used_Chinese_Characters) 常用字字形表;
- T = Taiwan, referring to [Standard Form of National Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Form_of_National_Characters) 國字標準字體;
- J = Japan, referring to [*Jōyō kanji*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji) 常用漢字;
- K = South Korea, which *I think* refers to [Basic *Hanja* for educational use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Hanja_for_educational_use) 漢文敎育用基礎漢字
- V = Vietnam (I'm not sure which standard this is referring to though)

---

The presence of a letter indicates that the given IDS is true for the corresponding standard; GHTJK means the given IDS is true for PRC & Singapore, Hong Kong, Taiwan, Japan, and South Korea.

Comment: The full doco is at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:Han_char#Notes .  Observe also that there _are_ tooltips for each of the characters.

Comment: @JdeBP thank you, I've corrected the answer.